# FillInIntent not firing

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, remoteview

I am trying to implement a collection widget that starts the main activity of my app when I click on one of its items. For some reason, the  views on the list are clickable (I see the ripple effect when I do it) but no intent is being launched.

Can you help me to find where I went wrong?

This is the implementation of the widget

```
public class StockWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

            RemoteViews views = initViews(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyStocksActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                    .getActivity(context,0,intent,0);
            views.setPendingIntentTemplate(R.id.widgetCollectionList,pendingIntent);


            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
        super.onUpdate(context,appWidgetManager,appWidgetIds);
    }

    private RemoteViews initViews(Context context, AppWidgetManager widgetManager, int widgetId) {
        RemoteViews mView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, StockWidgetService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME)));
        mView.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.widgetCollectionList, intent);

        return mView;
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }
}
```

This is the class that creates and delivers the remote views:

```
public class WidgetDataProvider implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {

    List<String> mCollections = new ArrayList<>();

    Context mContext = null;

    public WidgetDataProvider(Context mContext, Intent intent) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mCollections.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        RemoteViews mView = new RemoteViews(
                mContext.getPackageName(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        mView.setTextViewText(android.R.id.text1, mCollections.get(position));
        mView.setTextColor(android.R.id.text1, Color.BLACK);

        final Intent fillInIntent = new Intent(mContext, MyStocksActivity.class);
        fillInIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mView.setOnClickFillInIntent(android.R.id.text1,fillInIntent);

        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        initData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {
        initData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    private void initData() {
        mCollections.clear();
        for (int i=0; i<10;i++) {
            mCollections.add("Listview item" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the service that requests the remote views for the widget:

```
public class StockWidgetService extends RemoteViewsService {
    @Override
    public RemoteViewsFactory onGetViewFactory(Intent intent) {
        return new WidgetDataProvider(getApplicationContext(),intent);
    }
}
```

P.S.: I declared all of the components in the manifest.

Answer (score -2):

You create your intent but you never fire it.

```
final Intent fillInIntent = new Intent(mContext, MyStocksActivity.class);
fillInIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(fillInIntent);
```

startActivity() must be called

also im not familiar with this line

```
mView.setOnClickFillInIntent(android.R.id.text1,fillInIntent);
```

but if you're trying to set a click listener you would need to call startActivity(fillInIntent); from inside that listener

Comment: Basically, setOnClickFillInIntent sets an intent for a view that triggers when it is clicked. That line should create  the callback for when the view is clicked and launch the intent.